# Array not updating when doing setState()

Tags: react-native, setstate

I am implementing search functionality in my app. For displaying data I'm using **FlatList**. I tried all the methods on the web, but still I am unable to refresh my list based on search word.

```
<AppTextInput
    placeholder="Search"
    onChangeText={text => {
        var backUp = [...this.state.originalData];
        var temp = backUp.filter(item => {
            if (item.toLowerCase().match(text.toLowerCase())) {
                return item;
            }
        });
        this.setState({
            originalData: temp
        });
    }}
/>
<FlatList
    data={this.state.originalData}
    extraData={this.state}
    renderItem={item => (
        <View key={item.item}>
            <Text>{item.item}</Text>
        </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item}
/>
```

Please let me know how can I update the array in `setState()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach needs to be updated.
First, if you keep filtering original data in the states and updates it, you won't get correct result.
And do not use `this.state` as a `extraData` props for `FlatList`.
Instead save input keyword to the state and set that value as a `extraData` props for `FlatList`